# What is the easiest way to load a filtered .tda file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, large-files

Pandas has the excellent `.read_table()` function, but huge files result in a MemoryError.
Since I only need to load the lines that satisfy a certain condition, I'm looking for a way to only load those.

This could be done using a temporary file:

```
with open(hugeTdaFile) as huge:
    with open(hugeTdaFile + ".partial.tmp", "w") as tmp:
        tmp.write(huge.readline())  # the header line
        for line in huge:
            if SomeCondition(line):
                tmp.write(line)

t = pandas.read_table(tmp.name)
```

Is there a way to avoid such a use of a temp file?

Comment: This is bugging me, I feel there ought to be a way to read the file lazinly, so I asked this [more general python question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090685/lazyily-read-a-file-and-ignore-lines).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the chunksize parameter to return an iterator

see this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

- filter the chunk frames however you want
- append the filtered to a list
- concat at the end

(alternatively you could write them out to new csvs or HDFStores or whatever)

Comment: Does this work if none of the rows in a chunk meet the filter criteria? I was getting  'cannot append empty sequence' exception.

Comment: i think you might have to do: if len(filtered): l.append(filtered); concat haandles Nones, prob bug if it doesn't handle empty sequences